# Are AWS IAM user names case-sensitive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

As I'm creating users in AWS IAM, I want to know whether the user names are case-sensitive or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User names in AWS IAM are *case-insensitive*. You cannot create two users with the same name differing only in case.

When you log in as a user, the case of the user name does not matter.